# Activity result inside anonymous onClick method

Tags: java, android, android-activity, anonymous-function

I am starting to think that what I am doing may not be possible but I thought I would give SO a go before I abandon the idea.

Basically I have a EditText field called Path and I want to be able to browse to a file on the phones directory and pass back the file path.

Now forgive me if my terms are not correct, I am fairly new to Android and Java and have came from c# background. The Main activity pops up a dialog when a button is clicked. This is handled with the overridden onClick(). So the dialog now is contained in the context of the clicked method (I believe) so in order to add an onClick() to my path browse button I have used the following line.

```
((Button)customView.findViewById(R.id.SetPathButton)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent fileExploreIntent = new Intent(
                    FileBrowserActivity.INTENT_ACTION_SELECT_FILE,
                    null,
                    MainActivity.this,
                    FileBrowserActivity.class
            );

            startActivityForResult(fileExploreIntent, REQUEST_FILE_ID);
      }

      protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            Log.w("Activity Result", "Entered");
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_FILE_ID && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                String filename = data.getStringExtra(FileBrowserActivity.returnFileParameter);

                EditText path = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.SetPath));

                path.setText(filename);

          }
      }

 }
```

the onClick() inside the anonymous delegate (This may be a c# term sorry) creates an intent based on my FileBrowser activity which I have made and then calls it by using

```
startActivityForResult(fileExploreIntent, REQUEST_FILE_ID);
```

It is my understanding that after this intent is terminated it calls the `onActivityResult` method

The problem I am having is that the code is not going into the `onActivityResult` method. I think that whats happening is, as soon as it has clicked and gone through the onClick method the anonymous delegate gets destroyed leaving no place for the activity to return the result.

So I need to know, **how can I get a result back from my file browsing intent?** I have tried moving the method from the anonymous delegate into the `MainActivity` because I assumed it would be calling it based on the context you pass in however this causes my app to crash after I select a file, it only doesn't crash if I have it in my anonymous delegate. That suggests to me that it knows that it exists but doesn't go into it.

**Is it possible to do what I want?** My colleague is using Async tasks to kick off different activities in his program but this is a different program which is using intents so I don't really want to break consistency in the app.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html - sais: It's up to you because it is your implementation.

Comment: @Fildor. Thanks for your comment, that confirms what I thought I knew about getting the result but maybe my question wasn't clear enough, I am calling the startActivityForResult from within an anonymous method and it doesn't appear to be calling it.

Comment: Maybe check for data to be null inside the if, so you can see if it is called in the first place. I do not believe it has anything to do with whether the Intent is started form an anonymous event handler.

Comment: Aaahhh ... Move onActivityResult outside setOnClickListener ... nearly missed it.

Comment: @Fildor I did try that but it causes the app to crash. I have just tried it again and looking at the crash the error message is a bit misleading, it says that it couldn't deliver the message which I thought was because it didn't know where to deliver the message but its not, i think there's a null in the code somewhere which is causing it to crash. I shall investigate and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Only remove the below line from onActivityResult and add into oncreate method after setContentView.

```
EditText path = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.SetPath));
```

and make "EditText path" is a class(Global) variable.